# Error: [ng:btstrpd] App already bootstrapped with this element '&lt;crm-angular-js modules="crmDashboard"&gt;'

Tags: drupal, dashboard, angular

Getting this Error: `[ng:btstrpd] App already bootstrapped with this element '&lt;crm-angular-js modules="crmDashboard"&gt;'` on Dashboard with the only "CiviCRM News" enabled and empty.  What would it be?
**Drupal 7.9, CiviCRM 5.51.1**

Comment: I have similar error message with Drupal 9 and CiviCRM 5.51.1 and only "CiviCRM Resources" dashlet active. For me it seems that it just appears after upgrading to PHP 8.0... I updated CiviCRM today and on my first test this error did not appear (with PHP 7.3). We just updated to PHP 8.0 and now I get this error: `angular.min.js?r=0BEcoen_US:129 Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bcrm-angular-js%20modules%3D%22crmDashboard%22%26gt%3B`

Comment: @TobiasKrause Thank you, good to know I'm not alone :-) On the bright side, I've fixed this one by replacing **civicrm_dashboard**  table in the database by one taken from a fresh empty civicrm setup. Going to examine differences between the tables, there must be something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Drupal 7**

Broken upgrade, try to replace database tables  (civicrm_dashboard/_menu/_navigation) with vanilla tables

**Drupal 8/9**

According to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2975 there is one extra command to run after

```
composer civicrm:publish
```

This bit might worth adding to https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal8/ unless things have been changed ( for instance, my D9 composer.json has a different "required" section. ).

Comment: composer civicrm:publish
fixed it here. I'll add it to the System Admin Guide. Thank you @yurg

Comment: @Stoob added it to the System Admin Guide two days ago.